# Import products via TXT files

Tags: import, magmi, csv

Is there a way to import product information via TXT files into Magento? Supplier has only TXT files and no CSV available. I have the impression that MAGMI does not support TXT file type.

Comment: You could build a custom script quite easily, given your TXT file provider can format it the way your want, separating data by semi-column, pipe or whatever you like.

Comment: Yes the TXT files in question are tab separated and I think it's even possible to get them separated by some other character. But there is nothing easy in building the custom script you mentioned :)

Comment: I've done this at least 10 times, I can assure you it is really easy, you'll find plenty of those on the web, just google it.

Answer (score 2):

Since TXT files have no predefined structure I highly doubt there is any Import extension out there that will support importing your file out of the box.
My guess is that you'll probably have to build a script yourself. At least for the data extraction part.

I would advice building a script that extracts the product data and writes it to a CSV or XML file which then can be processed by MAGMI for example.
This way you leave the heavy lifting, importing products, to the extension and leaves you with just building a small converter.

Comment: That crossed my mind, but I'm not skilled enough to make such a script. There are separators in the TXT files in question so I guess it could be done and maybe even make it an automated process via cron and after that import the files into Magento with MAGMI + cron.

Comment: can you post a snippet of your TXT file with your question?